# Define OAuth 2.0 Token Request in Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I'm trying to understand OAuth 2.0 which is scarcely, badly documented and I'm trying to implement OAuth 2.0 client call in my App. I am using Postman to simulate API calls, which works. Postman shows big orange button "Get New Access Token", where I select Grant Type, URL, Client ID, Client Secret, Scope and Authentication type. Upon clicking button Request Token, new bearer token is returned by the API, meaning the authentication succeeded. This of course is completely useless approach to me, because I have no idea what just happened. I need to create actual request that shows me exactly how it is formed, so that successful response with bearer token is returned. Postman, for absolutely no reason, will not let me see that or convert it's useless UI into a functional API request. All I have is black box with orange button "Request Token", which does who knows what.

Does anyone know, how to form a working OAuth 2.0 bearer token request in Postman, preferably to convert their useless token request dialog directly into a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have been able to form a valid OAuth2 token request. For clarity, here is a code sample, which we need to convert to Postman response:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api_address/token");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic hash");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The `hash` part of the request is formed from `client_id` and `client_secret` values. In Postman, this is defined as such:

1. Create a simple POST request with token API url.
2. Go to `Authorization` tab.
3. Select `Basic Auth`
4. Enter `client_id` and `client_secret` into corresponding fields as username and password.
5. Go to `Body` tab.
6. Select `x-www-form-urlencoded`.
7. Enter key `grant_type` with value of `client_credentials`.

This example is for the *client credentials* flow. OAuth2 authors felt that calling auth scenarios as auth scenarios isn't cool enough, so they are called flows, which is nonsense, but sounds cooler.

Answer (score 0):

Process one:
[image: Process one]

Process two:
[image: Process two]

First, determine whether your token is passed through the header

It could be:

else process:
[image: else process]

Comment: Your approach appears to be a manual on how to enrich regular API calls with bearer token I already have. What the question is trying to describe is how am I going to request the bearer token without going through Postman UI request-making tool, and instead define a valid request myself.